# search for a regex expression variable with an exclude expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to search for an expression (`var exp = "foo"`) in a big `stringText` that includes `exp` **but excludes everything starting with '<' and ends with '>'*

right now I know how to write it like this:

```
    var regexp = new RegExp(exp, 'g');
    match = regexp.exec(stringText)
```

How do I write the exclude condition?

I know it should be `/<.+>/g` but how do I combine it? I know this isn't right but how do I do it?

```
    var regexp = new RegExp(exp + /<.+>/, 'g');
```

thanks, Alon

== UPDATE ===

I want to search for 'a' inside this string:

```
"a dog <span class="something"> had a  </span> and a cat"
```

I want it to hit the first 'a', the 'a' inside 'had', the 'a' after that and the 'a' in 'and' 'a' 'cat'

**I dont want to get 'a'** in 'span' or 'class' or everthing inside <>

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually looking for.  You seem to be saying "I want to find A and exclude B", but how are A & B related?

Comment: Can you give an example of things you do and don't want to be matched? From the way I read it you want `foo` but not `<foo>` -- what about `< this is foo>`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue you should look to something other than regex if you want to parse html/xml. Better men than I have [explained why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

If you're hell bent on using regex or your problem doesn't warrant a more robust solution, I'd suggest doing something like this since JS doesn't have lookbehind:

```
var input = "a dog <span class='something'> had a  </span> and a cat";

// Remove anything tag-like
var temp = input.replace(/<.+?>/g, "");

// Perform the search
var matches = new RegExp(exp, "g").exec(temp);
```

Or the one liner:

```
var matches = new RegExp(exp, "g").exec(input.replace(/<.+?>/g, ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want seem to be negative lookback and lookahead. Unfortunately, there is not lookback in javascript. Only lookahead.

E.g.

```
/foo(?!bar)/g
```

will match `foo` in `the foo fighters`, but it will not match `foo` in `the foobar solution`

So you might want something like

```
/foo(?!>)/g
```

You can study lookahead on http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead and javascript regexpes on http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: but if I will look for "foo < foo span>" then both of them will be excluded because they both come after '>' (and I want the first foo to be okay) - can't I say: "include only if there is no <> or if there is an '>' that wasn't followed by '<' ?

Comment: no, lookahead works just like any other regular expressions. /foo(?!bar)/ will match the first and the last foo's in "foo bar foobar foo". /foo(?!.*bar)/ however will only match the last foo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is most easily accomplished by at first removing (replacing with an empty string) all occurances of html-tags with a regexp such as this

```
var tmp = exp.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
```

Then you can easily match your regexp looking for a's in your new temporary html-less string.